# How to create a .NET quantity dropdown

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am not a .NET coder but I have to update a form. The form is built dynamically and a few items have quantity fields. I want to change the text boxes for quantities to a drop down that hast the number 1 thru @item.MaxAmt (each item has a value for the max. quantity allowed).

How would I write the dropdown code in .NET/cshtml? Something like this...

```
@Html.DropDownList("MaxQty",1-@item.MaxAmt)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to make use of `Enumerable.Range`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MaxQty", Enumerable.Range(1,@item.MaxAmt))
```

This method

> Generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range.

The method's signature is the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(
    int start,
    int count
)
```

where `start` is the value of the *first integer in the sequence* and `count` is *the number of sequential integers* to generate.

If you need more information, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx).